# Effectively getting items from map based on specific sort

Tags: c++, sorting, dictionary

I have a fairly easy problem: I have an `std::map<int,T>` and another `std::set<int>` (can be `std::vector` or similar too).

In the map I store items, and in the other container I'm storing favorites (of the map).

At some point, I'd need to retrieve (all) items from the map, but starting with the favorites defined by the other container.

Here is my minimal repro, I solved it very ugly, and ineffective:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

map<int, string> myMap;
set<int> myFavorites;


int main()
{
    
    myMap.emplace(1, "but I don't like this");
    myMap.emplace(12, "So it will go below");
    myMap.emplace(31, "This one will come first, and");
    myMap.emplace(44, "under my favorites");
    myMap.emplace(52, "then this will follow");
    
    myFavorites.insert(52);
    myFavorites.insert(31);
    
    cout << "My map:" << endl;
    for(auto p : myMap) {
        cout << "#" << p.first << "=" << p.second << endl;
    }
    
    cout << endl << "My favorites:" << endl;
    for(auto p : myFavorites) {
        cout << "#" << p << endl;
    }
    
    cout << endl << "All items starting with my favorites:" << endl;
    for(auto p : myFavorites) {
        auto item = myMap.find(p);
        if (item != myMap.end()) cout << "#" << item->first << "=" << item->second << endl;
    }
    for(auto p : myMap) {
        if (myFavorites.find(p.first) != myFavorites.end()) continue;
        cout << "#" << p.first << "=" << p.second << endl;
    }
}
```

What really bothers me is the last loop, where each iterations would call `find` on the `set`.

Required output is:

```
All items starting with my favorites:
#31=This one will come first, and
#52=then this will follow
#1=but I don't like this
#12=So it will go below
#44=under my favorites
```

Here is the above source in Coliru for making it easier: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/731fa76d90bfab00

Both map and set might be changed, but replacements needs to implement the same interfaces as originals.

I'm looking for a way to solve this more efficient than my original "brute-force" one.

Please note: map must not be "reordered"! I just need to query (retrieve) its items with custom sorting!

Note2: I know map can have a comparison operator. But I'd need to have the original order usually, and sometimes I'd need to have the custom sort!

Note3: Boost is not available and compiler is C++14 capable.

Comment: Perhaps you could consider using extra storage, specifically, a `vector <pair<int, T>>` called "favorite" and one called "other". Then, you could achieve this sort of output by simply iterating through all the map elements - for each element, check if it's in the "favorites" set. If it is, then add it to "favorite", and otherwise add it to "other". In the end, to get the output, just first print everything in "favorite" then print everything in "other". The problem with this is the storage requirement could be equal to the size of the map, which might be bad if the map is big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `std::map` and `std::set` use the same strict weak ordering for ordering its contents.

You can take advantage of this. You know that if you iterate over the map you will get the keys in the same order as they are in the set, therefore all it takes is a little bit of clever logic, something like:

```
auto map_iter=myMap.begin();

for(auto p : myFavorites) {
    while (map_iter != myMap.end())
    {
         if (map_iter->first == p)
            cout << "#" << map_iter->first << "=" << map_iter->second << endl;
         if (map_iter->first > p)
              break;
         ++map_iter;
     }
}
```

It may still make sense to use `find()` in some edge cases, specifically when `myFavorites` is significantly smaller than `myMap`, in which case a few calls to `find()` might be faster than iterating over (most of) the entire map.

Comment: But I need *all* items from the map, not just only the favorites. This one seems only extracting the favorites from the map.

Comment: Well, the inner loop iterates almost over the entire map, so simply do whatever you need to do with the other values in there, too, and add a final `while` loop iteration after this one, to cover the remaining values in the map. Do you understand how my example's logic works? If not, feel free to ask to clarify exactly what's unclear to you. If you do, then the minor modifications to this algorithm, to accomplish this, should be fairly straightforward.